# Override "table-layout: fixed" for a single row?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm creating a table with the styling `table-layout: fixed;`, and when you click on a row, it expands in height and gives you more information. To do this, I need to have a `<div>` element inside a `<td>` that takes up the entire width of the table. That means that I have to somehow override the fixed table layout for a single `<td>` in one row. I tried the following:

```css
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 75vw;  /* Full table is 75vw; each cell is ~18vw */
}

.expanded {
  width: 75vw !important;  /* Make expanded <td> element full table width */
}
```

This didn't work, and it remained the same size. Is there another way to override the `table-layout: fixed;` attribute?

Comment: hi please upload as much of your code as possible inside " >< " tab when editing.

Comment: Use [colspan](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_colspan.asp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A snippet to show you how to use [colspan](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_colspan.asp) to create a table cell which stretches the entire width of the table, and how to hide and show a row containing that cell.

```js
// hide every even row
document.querySelectorAll('tr:nth-child(even)').forEach(e => {
  e.classList.add('hidden')
})

// on every odd row, add a click handler to show/hide the following row
document.querySelectorAll('tr:nth-child(odd)').forEach(e => {
  e.addEventListener('click', evt => {
    evt.target.closest('tr').nextElementSibling.classList.toggle('hidden')
  })
})
```

```css
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

tr:nth-child(odd) {
  cursor: pointer;
}

tr:nth-child(odd):hover {
  background: yellow;
}

td {
  padding: 3px 10px;
  border: 1px solid silver;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Click</td>
    <td>me</td>
    <td>to</td>
    <td>see</td>
    <td>more</td>
    <td>information</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="6">Here is some more information</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Lorem</td>
    <td>ipsum</td>
    <td>dolor</td>
    <td>sit</td>
    <td>amet</td>
    <td>consectetur</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="6">Sed vulputate nibh elit, sed cursus felis rhoncus vitae.</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```